# Which user does oozie impersonate when submitting job through a coordinator

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

How does user impersonation/propagation work in oozie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default oozie executes all its jobs as oozie user itself.

There are options to impersonate any user and run oozie jobs, Ideally required when executing in kerborized environments and other restricted clusters.

refer [this](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/AG_Install.html) - User Authorization Configuration

Answer (score 2):

Check [User Propogation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a6_User_Propagation) from Oozie Docs.

It says

> When submitting a workflow job, the configuration must contain a
>   user.name property

When you don't explicitly add this property it is assigned the user submitting the job.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the logs I found there were three users

```
HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=hdfs:
HADOOP_YARN_USER=yarn:
USER=gaurav:
```

so while writing the files in HDFS via a job ran using oozie workflow or coordinator we must check that all these three user should have permission on that HDFS file/directory.